# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(a+2x\right)-2\sin\left(a+x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)}{x^{2}}$ without L'Hôpital

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

This limit is one of the "Problems Plus" from Stewart Calculus:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\left(a+2x\right)-2\sin\left(a+x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)}{x^{2}}$$

Note that the limit is of the indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. The problem appears several chapters before L'Hôpital's rule is discussed, so I assume there is a solution without using L'Hopital.

Looking at a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jbfxyfgwqy), the local behavior of the function near $0$ appears to be $-\sin(a+x)$, which, of course, suggests a limit of $-\sin(a)$. Using L'Hôpital's rule twice confirms this guess:

$$\begin{align}
& \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d}{dx} [\sin\left(a+2x\right)-2\sin\left(a+x\right)+\sin\left(a\right)]}{ \frac{d}{dx} x^{2}} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\cos(a+2x)-2\cos(a+x)}{2x} \\
& = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{-4\sin(a+2x)+2\sin(a+x)}{2} \\
& = -\sin(a).
\end{align}$$

Can anyone give a hint or solution for evaluating this limit without L'Hôpital?

Comment: Are you sure about that $\sin(a+x)-2\sin(a+x)$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos whoops, the first terms is $\sin(a+2x)$. I will modify my question, but my whole discussion is invalid now. Should I throw it out?

Comment: Just edit your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's first expand the $\sin$ functions using the addition formulae,
$$\sin(a+2x) = \sin(a) \cos(2x) + \cos(a) \sin(2x)$$
and similarly
$$\sin(a+x) = \sin a \cos x + \cos a \sin x$$
Expand $x$-dependent $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms to second order,
$$\sin x = x + O(x^3), \quad \cos x = 1 - \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^4)$$
so that we have (writing $S = \sin a$ and $C = \cos a$ for readability)
$$\sin(a+2x) = S \cdot \left(1-2x^2\right) + 2Cx + o(x^2)$$
and
$$\sin(a+x) = S \cdot \left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right) + Cx + o(x^2)$$
Now substitute these into the numerator of interest,

\begin{align*}
\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a) &= S \cdot\left(1-2x^2\right) + 2Cx - 2\left[S\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+Cx\right]+S+o(x^2) \\
&= \left(S - 2S + S\right) + x\left[ 2C-2C \right] + x^2 \left[ -2S + S \right] + o(x^2) \\
&= -Sx^2 + o(x^2)
\end{align*}
where we've collected coefficients by powers of $x$ (which is a somewhat messy experience, but it collects nicely) and hence we have
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(a+2x)-2\sin(a+x)+\sin(a)}{x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \left[ -S + \frac{o(x^2)}{x^2} \right] = -S$$
which gives the desired result.

---

As a side note, L'Hôpital is essentially doing all this expansion and cancelling for us by the machinery of differentiation. In particular, if $f(x) = Ax^2 + o(x^2)$, then
$$\frac{f(x)}{x^2} \to A \text{ as } x \to 0$$
which we can "extract" by noting that
$$f''(0) = 2A$$ so that
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\frac{d^2}{dx^2} f(x)}{\frac{d^2}{dx^2} x^2} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2A + o(1)}{2} = A$$
Of course, the true story is somewhat more involved (since denominators need not be $x^k$), but I find this a useful intuition to have. If you  know about complex residues, I also like to think of this as essentially analogous to [residues at higher order poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Limit_formula_for_higher_order_poles) (since we're extracting a coefficient of an expansion).

Answer (score 2):

Without heavy machinery, only that $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin x / x = 1$, you can use the [sum-to-product formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities), as follows.
\begin{align*}
\sin(a+2x) - 2 \sin(a+x) + \sin a & = \sin(a+2x) - \sin(a+x) + \sin a - \sin(a+x) \\
& = 2 \sin(x/2) \cos(a + 3x/2) - 2 \sin (x/2) \cos(a + x/2) \\
& = 2 \sin(x/2) \left (\cos(a + 3x/2) - \cos(a + x/2) \right ) \\
& = - 4 \sin(x/2) \sin(a+x) \sin(x/2) \\
& = - 4 \sin^2(x/2) \sin(a+x).
\end{align*}

Then
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{x^2} = \frac14 \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin^2(x/2)}{(x/2)^2} = \frac14 \lim_{y \to 0} \left ( \frac{\sin y}{y} \right )^2 = \frac14,
$$
and finally the limit of the expression you are looking at is indeed
$$
-4 \times \frac14 \times \sin a = - \sin a.
$$